# Help me use emacs with org mode at work

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, wsl

**When working from home on my linux machine** - I have all my org files on Dropbox. I store all agenda files, todos, references and stuff like that in those. Basically my whole life is in those org files. If I am away from a computer during the day I have an idea or I want to check my agenda - I can easily do so through an app called "orgzly". All is well for now.

Now imagine if I wanted to take notes **while I am at work on a windows machine**(I am an IT technician in a large factory. Also doing some development work, writing documentation for it, etc. A good code editor is a must)... I would of course also try to use emacs with org mode(writing in a word document and not having my shortcuts for text editing, hunting and pecking with mouse simply kills me). I would also try to make agendas and schedule tasks, keep track of projects and use everything that emacs and org mode has to offer.

## Here are some **problems** that I face:

- my work machine is a windows machine. **[It means that magit is slow as hell](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Microsoft-Windows-Performance.html)**, I can not work with it being so slow..
- I still want to keep my config similar on both personal and work machines, so **I have to make my .emacs config usable on both windows and linux**. [I found a way to do that that already](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingBoth), it works fine.
- **installing dropbox on my work machine** and then syncing all my life files(journals, ideas, birthdays, errands, etc) to work machine does not sound like a good idea. I don't want someone to be able to see my personal files just in case someone takes my laptop or I leave this workplace without cleaning my computer first.
- it means that I have to **separate my org files into personal/work**. Have work files ONLY at work and personal ONLY at home. But that frustrates me again, because now I can not see the big picture when I am at work looking at my week. I would much rather prefer to filter work/personal tasks in agenda itself by creatig separate `org-agenda-custom-commands`, letter w for work agenda, letter p for personal.

## **What I tried**:

- I have tried to **run a VM on my work computer** that is protected with a password and then have my dropbox with all my personal/work org files inside this VM and also run emacs directly there.
- **run emacs on WSL** which is installed on my work machine, but then I am running emacs in terminal, which does not give me full funcitonality, some bindings are messed up and similar problems.. (now I am aware you can insall graphical emacs on wsl, but dont think that would solve my issue of using org files at work)
- I have also tried creating **two github repositories**. one containing personal org files and another containing work org files. But then everyday I have to remember to push and pull.. (I guess I can create a cron job that syncs for me every 5mins or so).
- I was also thinking to **encrypt the org folder**, so only I could open it. That way I can keep dropbox on my work computer.
- I was also trying to do "**sparse checkout**" in git, which helps me to git clone only one folder from my org repo..
- I was also thinking perhaps **screw it all** and simply run my dropbox on work computer without being afraid that someone will get hold of my computer and see my personal files... but that is the last resort.
- Most recently I have tried to **launch a virtual VM in digitial ocean**. Cheapest, for 4$ a month(1vcpu-512mb-10gb) and run ubuntu there, have [headless dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux) and emacs inside of it, ssh into it at work from a windows machine over [mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)(I am asked for password, so only I can access it), to have emacs with a GUI. It works quite well. Today will be my second day using this setup. What I think now.. I could perhaps install emacs directly at my windows work computer and then use tramp to connect to this virtual VM where all my org files reside.
- Or finally I should **quit this IT technician job** and get myself a programmer role where linux is encouraged, might make some things easier. (it's coming, but not for now).

Yeah, I am confused and lost a little. I keep thinking what is the best way to make it work.

I finally want to get done with it and continue building stuff rather than trying to configure my emacs environment(even thought I learn a lot while doing so. Not only about emacs, but about VM's, ssh, wsl and stuff) :)

Curious to know how others have set up this or perhaps you have some suggestions for my situation.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! You write "Here are some problems that I face"; please instead write each separate question such that it asks for a specific, correct answer. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question may not be specific enough, and I think it might be more appropriate to post it on Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a GNU/Linux at work you would still face the privacy issue. So in any case here's what I'd do regarding data segregation.

So let's say `A` is your computer at home and `B` is your computer at work.

On `A` I'd have

- an `Orgzly` folder to put all my Agenda org
  files, plus the org files I want to be able to edit with my smartphone.
- an `Org-Mode` folder to put the rest of my org files. In regard to work, on `Org-Mode`, there would 2 different kinds of files: those I want to share with `B` and those I don't want to share with `B`. You can put the first kind in a `Shared` folder and the second in a `Private` folder.

On `B` your work-related org files could be put inside of a `Work` folder (a subfolder of `Shared`)

So you'd just have to sync `Shared` between `A` and `B`.

Regarding your Agenda files you could also have a `Todo` folder within `Work` for your agenda files related to work, and add this folder to Orgzly through Syncthing. So you would have a complete view of your tasks on your smartphone (you could also have a complete view at home if you'd like to).

As for the Emacs config file, I'd recommend writing it in an org file (let's say `emacsinit.org` that you would put somewhere in `Shared`. Then you'd just have to write this in your .emacs (on GNU/Linux, Windows or macOS):

```lisp
(require 'org)
(org-babel-load-file "PATH/emacsinit.org")
```

So your config file could be easily synchronized.

Also, Dropbox has access to all your files, so I wouldn't use it. Use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) instead.